# Different scales on the same plot

Tags: pgfplots

I would like to know whether and how the `pgfplots` package can be used to produce a plot with two curves using different scales, like in the following example:
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See section 4.8.10 – "Two Ordinates (*y* axis) or Multiple Axes" – in the [pgfplots manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.pdf). The following is ripped from the first example (with preamble added):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    axis y line*=left,% the ’*’ avoids arrow heads
    xlabel=$x$,
    ylabel=First ordinate]
  \addplot {x^2};
  \end{axis}
  \begin{axis}[
    scale only axis,
    xmin=-5,xmax=5,
    axis y line*=right,
    axis x line=none,
    ylabel=Second ordinate]
    \addplot[red] {3*x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. -- For anyone else searching for that manual section: in the current version (pgfglots 1.14) it moved to section [4.9.11](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#272).