# pgfplots and backgrounds library

Tags: pgfplots, backgrounds

When I use `framed` option from `backgrounds` tikz library for axis environment, this example works ok:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=both]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[xshift=2cm,yshift=3cm,width=4cm,framed]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but for more complicated background styles, like
`background rectangle/.style={draw=red,fill=white},show background rectangle`
nothing happend (howewer frame around subplot still appears).

If I use wrapping of `axis` environment into additional `tikzpicture` like this one:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=both]
\end{axis}

\begin{tikzpicture}[background rectangle/.style={draw=red,fill=white},
    show background rectangle]
  \begin{axis}[xshift=2cm,yshift=3cm,width=4cm]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

backgound ok, but positioning fails.

How could I use backrounds with pgfplots?

Similar question: how to use backgrounds for several axis together (it's useful for different right and left axis in one plot).

Comment: For using several axes together, you don't really need the `backgrounds` library. There's a standard way for getting multiple axes described in the answer to [Different Scales on the Same Plot](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21975/different-scales-on-the-same-plot/21979#21979)

Comment: @Jake: yes, I know. But if background applied to the one of `axis`, label of another one appears outside background rect. I try to apply `/tikz/background/.style={}` to the `scope` wrapping around of both axis, but nothing happened.

Comment: If you have nothing else in picture you could just apply the style to the whole `tikzpicture` environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Options provided to the `axis` environment are in the `/pgfplots` key tree, but the `backgrounds` options have to be provided as `/tikz/background/.style={}`. Your example would thus look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[grid=both]
\end{axis}


\begin{axis}[
    xshift=2cm,
    yshift=3cm,
    width=4cm,
    /tikz/background rectangle/.style={
        fill=yellow,
        draw=blue
    },
    show background rectangle]
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pgfplots axis with background]

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting, why `framed` acts anyway?